# Access to array (member of structure) in array of structures in C

Tags: c++

I have problem with access to array (member of structure) in array of structures.
Code sample:

```
struct SV
{
    int station;
    double* tab;
    SV()
    {
     double* tab= new double[3];
    }

};

int main()
{
    SV* SUV = new SV[10];

    SUV[0].station = 10; // works
    SUV[0].tab[0] = 10; //  how it should be done?

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get access to this array? Is it possible in C?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would appear to be C++, not C.

Comment: OP, your code is C++, but your text says see. Now which one is it?

Comment: You have missing semicolons after the first 3 statements in main. If you put them at the end it compiles ok. Not making any comments about the code only that it compiles (it compiles mutatis mutandis that is not as it is).

Comment: It is C/C++, I would like to make it working without using classes.

Comment: If you are using C++, then a `struct` is basically a `class`.

Comment: @orlowiczg There is not such thing as C/C++. Choose one.

Comment: in C++ everythig is object, class/structure is same thing, just class got default private access. If you'll consider struct to be different, you may get burned painfully.

Comment: Ok I should have written C++, thanks for your time!

Comment: `std::array<double>` or `std::vector<double>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `struct SV`:

```
struct SV
{
    int station;
    double* tab;
    SV()
    {
     double* tab= new double[3];
    }

};
```

In the constructor, you do:

```
double* tab= new double[3];
```

However, what you need to do is:

```
tab= new double[3];
```

The previous is not what you want since it creates a *new* array called `tab` local to the constructor, and does not initialize the one in your class. Trying to index this array will invoke undefined behavior, since `tab` doesn't point to anything. This also creates a memory leak, the since the local array is not `delete`d.

On the other hand, you could also do this in your constructor:

```
SV() : tab(new double[3]) {};
```

This would initialize `tab` in the constructor, not assign to it.

As a side note, I recommend that you check out [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to *greatly* simplify your task.